# Android - Fused Location Provider Client sometimes get wrong Location

Tags: android, android-service, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I want to get user's GPS location once a minute. I'm using below Service Class. But sometimes it's getting wrong location. I didn't switch off GPS or Data. I'm using Samsung Mobile (J7 Max).

As a example, in the attached image (**GPS Locations Image**) I was at Location **B**. But GPS gave Location **A**.

How can I resolve this error and get high accurate location?

[GPS Locations Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ4NY.png)

**LocationService.java**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;

    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS;
    private long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
        FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

        createLocationCallback();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createLocationCallback() {
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                try {
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                    //.... my code ....//

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    private void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of this is not your app, but the mistake was made by the phone. To ensure this, you can test your app on another phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
​I checked with some another Samsung phones (J2). Sometimes that phones also get wrong location.

Comment: Did you test the app in different places?

Comment: Yes. Different locations, different roads.
Is there any mistake/fault in my code implementation?

Comment: I didn't. Is this always happening?

Comment: Sometimes only.

Comment: So I guess it's not related to your app.